# How do I identify whether the word "quite" is used in the sense of completely or partly?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, ambiguity, understanding

I've found that word "quite" is used sometimes in the sense of "greatest extent" (or say absolute or complete sense) and sometimes "moderate extent" (or say somewhat or little sense) and taking the other sense than actual can cause misunderstanding as they stands for *quite* opposite sense.

So, How do I identify or the recognize which sense the word "quite" used in?

Comment: *Quite* is also tricky because it is used quite differently in American and British English.

Answer (score 2):

When used with an adjective or adjectival phrase

It means somewhat or to a degree when the adjective has gradual variability

```
It is quite warm
It is quite expensive
```

It means completely or to the utmost when the adjective has no gradual variability

```
It is quite wrong
It is quite unacceptable
```

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/quite

Comment: I think you might be putting the cart before the horse here. It's more a case of *when* "quite" means "somewhat", the following adjective has gradual variability *in that context*. And *when* it means "completely", the combination ***quite + adjective*** has no gradual variability. Think first about how you would normally interpret *it is quite cold*, then reassess that interpretation if I change it to ***until** it is quite cold.*

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about. Coldness has degrees of variability. Quite cold means somewhat cold not absolutely  freezing cold in both cases.

Comment: If I say *It is quite cold*, you'd normally interpret that as meaning ***somewhat*** cold. But if I say ***Wait until** it is quite cold*, you'd normally interpret that as ***completely*** cold. This even applies to adjectives that we wouldn't usually think of as being capable of gradation, such as [*(until) they are **quite dead**.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22until+they+are+quite+dead%22)

Comment: But the point is that coldness is an adjective which has degrees of strength, it doesn't have a set value. With those type of adjectives the word quite also has degrees of intensity which can be interpreted from the context.  Whereas with an adjective such as wrong, which has no variability, quite also has no variability.